# How to add angular element selector inside the ngFor

Tags: angular, angular7, web-component, ngfor, angular-elements

I have 4 angular elements (Web Components) in my projects. I have added script tag for those web components in index.html `<script src="web-angular-element.js"> </script>` and i want to display those elements dynamically in my angular application. i am just using the components selector to display that in application and name of selector is coming from the service like this `' based on the user access.

```html
<div class="widgets-section" *ngFor="let widgets of userWidget">
    <div class="wt">
        <h3>{{widgets.name}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="wb">
        {{widgets.code}}
    </div>
    <div class="wf">
        <button class="button-standard">{{widgets.text}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here widget code is `widgets.code = <component-name></component-name>` that is not working even i have tried the "ngTemplateOutlet"

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="widgets.code"></ng-container>

<ng-template #abc>
  <component-name></component-name>
</ng-template>
```

Here i am passing widget code is `widgets.code = "abc"` and based on the code i am trying to render the component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)

Comment: @Rectunglar Here i am talking about Angular elements like "web components"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind `ngTemplateOutlet` to a variable that is a `TemplateRef`.

This simple code below is not a full solution for your issue, but it will give you the solution for dynamic components. What is left for you to do is to get the correct `TemplateRef` by the `widget.code`.

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="carrentTemplate"></ng-container>

<ng-template #abc>
  <component-name></component-name>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #def>
  <component-name-2></component-name-2>
</ng-template>
```

TS:

```
carrentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
@ViewChild('abc') abc: TemplateRef<any>;
@ViewChild('def') def: TemplateRef<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  if (true) { // some condition
    this.currentTemplate = this.abc;
  } else  {
    this.currentTemplate = this.def;
  }
}
```